# What is difference between factory and factoryboy package?

Tags: django, factory, factory-boy

I am new to the factoryboy package i want to use this for unit testing of my django app, previously i used factory package,

i want to know the exact difference between this 2 package becuase syntax and structure is almost same in both package

Comment: [factoryboy](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) is for creating fixture(fake data) while [factory](https://pypi.org/project/Factory/) is for method pattern. There are no rule about naming package so sometime you get 2 packages that almost name like each other, but they are not the same